# Counting files and commits

Tags: git, zsh

## 1. I want to count untracked files.

Currently, I use a command like below.

```
> git status -s | egrep '^\?\?' | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

However, if there is a newly added directory, it just count 1. `git status -s` command ignores how many files in the directory.

So, I change the command like below.

```
> git ls-files -o | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

However, this command counts whole untracked files. I want to uncount in .gitignore patterns.

How can I do this?

## 2. Difference with local to remote branch

I use a command like below for this.

```
> git rev-list --left-right --count master...origin/master | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

But, this command works only when I execute a fetch command.

I use this command on my own zsh plugin.

So, It should be automatically calculated difference with local to remote.

How can I do this?

---

Added.

I want to execute `git fetch` once when I change a directory that is git repository. This script runs with my own zsh theme.

```
+- Example (git repository)
 +- sub1
 +- sub2
  +- sub2-1
```

I change a directory to wherever in git repository then `git fetch` once. Suppose this to Example directory. Next, I change to sub1 and do not execute `git fetch`. Because it may no effect so I get a efficiency.

---

Please, Help me.

Comment: The `tr -d ' '` seems superfluous. `wc -l` does not add space padding when reading from a pipe. (Though you should also know about `grep -c` for counting the number of matching lines.)

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is no padding spaces. However, On MAC, there is a some padding spaces. I will try a `grep -c`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `git ls-files -o --exclude-standard`

`--exclude-standard` adds the standard Git exclusions: .git/info/exclude, .gitignore.

2. There is no way to count commits without fetching them first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. So, I add a question.